# Microsoft Office files to Images (JPEG/PNG)

Tags: php, windows, web-services, ms-office

I'm building a webapp, and I need the ability for users to view Word/Excel/PPT files in the browser (these files are stored server-side). So i decided it will be better to convert these files into thumbnail images

20 slides powerpoint to 20 images

What is the best way to do this or any other way around to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) can save to several formats, including PDF, tiff, png, and jpeg. It exposes a [COM API](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/com-interface) and provides samples for using it.

Instead of exposing the COM objects, it might be simpler to write a simple PowerShell or cmd.exe script to print the first page of the document to the PDF creator printer. You can use the open source utility [classExec](http://fvue.nl/wiki/ClassExec) to do this. [This page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ddecommandline.php) is a good reference for DDE in general.

Comment: PDFCreator installs as a printer, so you just install it and do File->Print. Job done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but this is stackoverflow and I assume he wants to automate the creation of these thumbnails.